# Would like to input a dynamic value in xpath in selenium, while using POM(PageFactory)

Tags: java, selenium, page-factory

I would like to create a method in selenium using PageFactory in which I can input dynamic (a variable) in xpath.

Below is the class I have created:

```
public class SelectingAnOrder {
  WebDriver driver;
  public SelectingAnOrder(){
    this.driver = driver;
   }
//    @FindBy(xpath = "(//td[contains(@class,'kPWJZB')])[5]")")
//    WebElement FindAnOrder;

  public WebElement SelectingAnOrder_selection(int var){    
     WebElement FindAnOrder = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//td[contains(@class,'kPWJZB')])["+var+"]"));
     FindAnOrder.click();
   }

 }
```

I am aware of using @FindBy(xpath = (//td[contains(@class,'kPWJZB')])[5]")) in the class itself, but I am not able to figure out as how to input a variable in @FindBy.

The variable is named as "var", which I want to make dynamic and would like to have a ability to input any int, while running the test case.

My Test case looks like this:

```
 WebDriver driver = DriverSetup.Driver_Setup("https://gdc1tatcweb001.../orders");

 SelectingAnOrder PickingAnOder = PageFactory.initElements(driver, SelectingAnOrder.class)
 PickingAnOder.SelectingAnOrder_selection();
```

While running the test, I am getting the below error.
**Cannot invoke method findElement() on null object**

Can anyone please help with using dynamic xpath in selenium using PageFactory?
I am open for any other ways or methods for implementing the same thing.

Comment: sounds like the driver is null... don't you need to pass that into the constructor?

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for your help, I was missing that part in my code. It works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The code wasn't working because I wasn't passing the driver in the constructor.
Changed the below line
 public SelectingAnOrder(){

to

public SelectingAnOrder(WebDriver driver){

and everything was working as expected.